# Ext js how to add panel to tab panel dynamicaly for tree node click?

Tags: extjs

I created border layout and added a tree panel to west region and a tab panel to center region.

I want to know how can I add another tab in tab panel for tree node click?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://examples.extjs.eu/?ex=dyntab) example will show you how to add tabs dynamically.
You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725613/extjs-add-single-click-action-to-a-node-in-a-treepanel) question for adding click actions to the nodes of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
var formPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({bla bla bla });
var tabPanel = ....  ;
tabPanel.add(formPanel);
tabPanel.doLayout();
```

This little snippet will allow you to add panels to your tab panel.  The suggestion above should help you handle the click events for your tree panel.